# Storing Class name in HTML localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use a theme selector that adds "dark" class name to HTML element.

like: `<html class="dark">`

I want to save class name in localStorage so it will be consistent even after page reload.

Here is my JS

```
(function () {
  window.__onThemeChange = function () { };
  function setTheme(newTheme) {
    window.__theme = newTheme;
    preferredTheme = newTheme;
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('class', newTheme);
    window.__onThemeChange(newTheme);
  }

  var preferredTheme;
  try {
    preferredTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  } catch (err) { }

  window.__setPreferredTheme = function (newTheme) {
    setTheme(newTheme);
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    } catch (err) { }
  }

  var darkQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)');

  darkQuery.addListener(function (e) {
    window.__setPreferredTheme(e.matches ? 'light' : 'dark');
  });

  setTheme(preferredTheme || (darkQuery.matches ? 'light' : 'dark'));
})();
```

Any idea how to correctly to save the `class="dark"` in localStorage?

Comment: I can store theme-data="dark" or any attribute but when I try to store class="dark" it doesn't work. 
Any idea how to store class="dark" in my example?

Answer (score 2):

What I'm seeing here is that in the function __setPreferredTheme you're stringifying a value 'light' or 'dark' and then parsing out this value in the variable preferredTheme, which causes an error cause you're parsing a string.
You should be able to just pass the value of the class in the function without using parse or stringify.

Comment: I edited my code and removed stringify but still cant get the class name stay. (edited question)

Comment: if I use data-theme="dark" it works and can store in localstorage. but if I use class="dark" it doesn't work. and I don't see any error.

Comment: In the code you're storing just the value 'dark' not the all statement. If you open the sources tab on the browser you can put debuggers inside the function and see what. is actually passed inside the setItem(). It should be just the value of the class by the way, to work properly.